# Ember template not showing any data

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-rails

I am just starting out with Ember.js and I am using ember-rails on the back end.  The problem that I am having is that I am getting a list of items but no data is being rendered in my template.

**router.js.coffee**

```
App.Router.map (match)->
# match('/').to('index')
   @resource "stories"
```

**stories_route.js.coffee**

```
App.StoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend
model: -> 
    App.Story.find()
```

**stories.handlebars**

```
<h1>Stories</h1>

<ul>
{{#each story in controller}}
      <li>{{story.title}} A</li>
{{else}}
      <li>There are no stories.</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>

{{outlet}}
```

Here is the JSON that I am getting back from Rails:

```
{
   "stories":[
      {
         "story":{
            "id":1,
            "title":"Test",
            "description":"This is a test story"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Edit:

I am able to get the correct template to render, it is just that the data is empty.

Here is what the HTML looks like:

```
<div id="ember295" class="ember-view">
   <h1>Stories</h1>
   <ul>
   <script id="metamorph-2-start" type="text/x-placeholder">
   </script>
   <script id="metamorph-4-start" type="text/x-placeholder">
   </script>
      <li>
         <script id="metamorph-5-start" type="text/x-placeholder">
         </script>
         <script id="metamorph-5-end" type="text/x-placeholder">
         </script>
         A
      </li>
    <script id="metamorph-4-end" type="text/x-placeholder">
    </script>
    <script id="metamorph-2-end" type="text/x-placeholder">
    </script>
  </ul>
  <script id="metamorph-3-start" type="text/x-placeholder">
  </script>
  <script id="metamorph-3-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: I've edited my answer reflecting a more simpler solution, have a look...

Comment: I guess that now the problem is your JSON, can you alter the API response serverside and remove the additionally `story` level?

Comment: Edited again my answer to cover you `new` problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `stories` is your first route and accessible at `"/"` then you can define a path like:

```
App.Router.map () ->
  @resource('stories', {path: '/'})
```

**OR** you can define an index route and redirect from there like:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  redirect: ->
    @transitionTo('stories')
```

See here a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ivizok/1/edit) that shows the second concept.

**EDIT**

I guess your problem is now that if your result contains a collection of records you need to remove the additional `story` level in your JSON resulting in something like:

```
{
  "stories":[
    {
      "id":1,
      "title":"Test",
      "description":"This is a test story"
    }
  ]
}
```

and for a single record e.g. `/stories/123` your JSON should look like:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "title":"Test",
  "description":"This is a test story"
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The correct template is getting rendered, it just that there is no data displayed.  It seems to know that there is a single item in the array so a `<li>` is created.

Comment: Yup, the JSON formatting was causing the issue.  I am using RABL so in the the rab_init.rb, I added `config.include_json_root = false`.  Thanks!